# changing the threshold voltage by controlling the oxide thickness in a p-mos

Tags: nmos, pmos

Can we change the threshold voltage by controlling the gate oxide thickness in a p-mos?

Comment: Consult your textbook about the MOS structure and MOS transistors and look what defines the Threshold voltage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks like a homework / exam question with no effort shown to find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

See for example

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_voltage#Dependence_on_oxide_thickness

or any textbook about MOS design.